# Oracle Apex Substitution Strings - can't add a new one

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm using Application Express 4.2.5.00.08 and have added a fresh application.

When I go to **Supporting Objects > Edit Substitutions** I am not able to add a new substitution string,  instead the page says

> *The application has no substitutions*.

Is this behaviour correct for Apex 4.2?  Is there a prior step in the Apex design life cycle that I'm missing?

(I'm not terribly familiar with APEX, but on an APEX 3 version I'm looking at, you *are* able to add new substitutions as the interface has lots of rows of empty inputs waiting to take new entries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing "Supporting Objects" with "Shared Components"

In fact, you can edit substitution string definitions by clicking "Edit application properties" above the big icons. In 3.x this was clicking on the application name.

Supporting objects is to help prepare for application delivery. The substitution string section is to allow the installer to specify the value of the string on install of the app.